# Can i make obejct of a VB class from C# class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

Can i make obejct of a VB class from C# class, if possible then what i'll have to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  You'll have to compile the VB class using the VB compiler first.  The easiest way to do this is to have the C# code and the VB code in separate assemblies, in separate projects.  You can then include the VB project as a reference in the C# project and use it that way.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly use a class in a dll created in vb.net in a C# project. However you won't be able to do that natively inside Visual Studio for the same project.

Answer (score 3):

1) Add reference to VB library you want to use.

2) Add namespace in your code.

3) Create your object and use it.